# How to delete Databricks data older than X days/years?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to set up a retention policy on the Databricks tables that I create, but I do not know how to do it. I am using these two configurations based on Databricks documentation:

- delta.logRetentionDuration = "interval ": Configure how
  long you can go back in time. Default is interval 30 days.
- delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration = "interval ": Configure
  how long stale data files are kept around before being deleted with
  VACUUM. Default is interval 1 week.

My table is at least 2 days old, and using an interval of 1 day is not effective, because I query the table and every row is still there, nothing is deleted. I also used the VACUUM command as follows:

VACUUM test_table RETAIN 10 HOURS

But, still, nothing is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Delta lake provides a vacuum command that **deletes older versions of the data** (any data that’s older than the specified retention period).

**Case1:** If you have a delta table without any changes, when you use vacuum command does not do anything.

**Case2:** If you have a delta table with any changes, when you use vacuum command does deletes older versions of the data.

You may refer this article "[Vacuuming Delta Lakes](https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/vacuum-command/)", which clearly explains with examples of when vacuum applies and not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: It won't delete vacuum (delete) any file is these file correspond to data that is part of the latest version of your table.